# How can I use c11 headers in openbsd?

Tags: c, gcc, c11, openbsd

I want to use specific c11 macros in my C code, but they aren't available. I installed gcc 8.4 via pkg_add on a fresh OpenBSD 7.1 install. `/usr/include/float.h` is missing any c11 definitions.

**gcc-8.4**:

```
sunfire$ egcc -std=c11 prog.c
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:5:17: error: 'FLT_DECIMAL_DIG' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'DECIMAL_DIG'?
printf("%d\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               DECIMAL_DIG
```

**clang-13.0.0**:

```
sunfire$ clang prog.c -std=c11                                                       
prog.c:5:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FLT_DECIMAL_DIG'
        printf("%d \n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG);
                        ^
1 error generated.
```

I looked into the FreeBSD headers and they ship with c11 definitions. Is there a reason OpenBSD does not include those definitions?

**Update:** Code to reproduce:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
        printf("%d \n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG);
}
```

Output on GNU/Linux x86-64 is `9\n`

Comment: Try running `find / float.h` to check if it even exists, maybe the linker doesn't find it because it isn't in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I think the problem is that I installed gcc 8.4 but it still uses the header files from the OpenBSD base system. No idea yet how I can get updated headers.

Comment: But does your clang find a `float.h` with `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` support? Not sure what I am doing wrong. Fresh OpenBSD 7.1 install. No c11 compatible `float.h` can be found on the whole system, neither gcc 8.4 (from pkg_add) nor clang (from system) ship c11 compatible `float.h` headers. Both support -std=c11.

Comment: Apparently, gcc-8.4 - when build from ports - ships its own c11 compatible `float.h` in `/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unkown-openbsd7.1/8.4.0/include`. No idea why this does not apply to the pkg_add version.